# Application of 2 discriminant functions

Tags: discriminant-analysis

Thank you for reading my question.

Recently, I tried to analyze my data using the discriminant function.

When classifying, I used 4 phases (specifically, the ages of the house were divided into 4 phases: 1 phase 0-5 yrs, 2 phase 5-15 yrs, 3 phase 15-30 yrs, 4 phase 30-50 yrs)
And I applied 4 variables (house size, electric cost, water cost, and rent fee)
I made the quadratic discriminant function using R studio, and then applied the function to the test set for checking the accuracy.
The accuracy was about 70%. I found that the accuracies of 1-3 phases were over 80%, while that of phase 4 was 40%.
To increase the accuracy I need to adjust something for phase 4.

If applying more variables (adding 2 or 3 variables), the accuracy of phase 4 increased. However, the accuracies of 1-3 phases decreased.
Consequently, the total accuracy was not different from the original one (using 4 variables).

I imagine that if I used 4 variables for 1-3 phases and 7 variables for phase 4, total accuracy might increase.
I am worried that it is possible. and I do not find a way how to apply different conditions to the discriminant function analysis.

Is it possible to use 4 variables for 1-3 phases and 7 variables for phase 4 to estimate the age of the house using the quadratic discriminant function, especially in R studio?
Thank you for sharing your advice.